# Декоратор функции в Python

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

Изучаю тему с декораторами, есть задание.
*Условие: Объявите функцию с именем get_sq , которая вычисляет площадь прямоугольника по двум
параметрам: width и height – ширина и высота прямоугольника и возвращает результат.
Определите декоратор для этой функции с именем (внешней функции) func_show , который
отображает результат на экране в виде строки (без кавычек): "Площадь прямоугольника:
<значение>". Вызовите декорированную функцию get_sq.*

Составил код, вроде бы все работает, но не уверен в правильности, т.к. цикл будет перебирать все аргументы, а не именно два: width и height.
Хотел бы узнать, как можно оформить именно для двух аргументов. И правильно ли вызван декоратор?
Буду признателен за объяснения и советы. Спасибо.

```
def func_show(func):

def get_sq(**kwargs):
    x = 1
    for v in kwargs.values():
        x *= int(v)
    func(x)
return get_sq


@func_show
def result(kwargs):
    print(f"Площадь прямоугольника: {kwargs}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result(width=4, height=6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код в принципе не будет работать - декоратор пустой, return get_sq вне функции, да и к чему перебор аргументов, если по заданию у вас их два...
Давайте подробнее разберем как надо

```
def func_show(func): # это наша функция декоратор
    # внутри декоратора у нас будет функция-обработчик, который и будет декорировать  оригинальную функцию
    # На вход этой функции примем те же аргументы что и оригинальная функция 
    def wrapper(width, height): 
        res = func(width, height) # обратимся к оригинальной функции для получения результата
        print(f"Площадь прямоугольника: {res}") # выведем текст в соответствии с заданием
        return res # и в конце вернем вычисленное значение (вдруг за декоратором кто-то им воспользоваться хотел)
    return wrapper # результат работы декоратора - вызов нашей функции-обработчика

# соственно декорирование вашей функции, вычисления площади
@func_show
def get_sq(width, height):
    return width*height


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # вызов декорированной функции
    get_sq(width=4, height=6)
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описание, свои ошибки понял, исправил, разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

скорее всего нужно вот так:

```
def get_sq(width, height):
    return width * height

def func_show(func):
    def decor(width, height):
        print(f"площадь прямоугольника: {func(width, height)}")

    return decor

get_sq = func_show(get_sq)

get_sq(4, 6)
```

если есть желание сохранить вывод как у первоначальной функции:

```
def get_sq(width, height):
    return width * height

def func_show(func):
    def decor(width, height):
        square = func(width, height)
        print(f"площадь прямоугольника: {square}")
        return square

    return decor

get_sq = func_show(get_sq)

res = get_sq(4, 6)
```